# Single quotes in gtag event reporting with click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager, event-tracking, gtag.js

I've been working with adding some event tracking with Google's gtag events and for the most part, everything is working correctly, but for some reason, I'm getting some single quotes back in the reporting and I'm not sure where they could be coming from.

Overall, I'm using a click event to pull some data attributes on specific links on a WordPress site.

This is what I have for my JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.ga--event').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var url = $this.data("url");
    var cat = $this.data("category");
    var auth = $this.data("author");
    $this.on('click', function() {
      gtag('event', "\'" + url + "\'", {
        'event_category': "\'" + cat + "\'",
        'event_label': "\'" + auth + "\'",
        'non_interaction': true
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I've `console.log` out those variables and everything seems correct and without the single quotes in the console, so I'm wondering if I'm not escaping my variables correctly? Is there any way to `console.log` the full event and see if that's adding the single quotes?

Comment: You get single quotes because you add them in your code. Instead of e.g. 'event_label': "\'" + auth + "\'" you can just do 'event_label': auth. No escaping is necessary at this point.

Comment: @EikePierstorff - Yeah, I kinda figured that after I posted this and started to look at it again as a whole. Looks like removing the escaping fixed it. Thanks!